# Move Images from ladder Sub folders to Main Folder using C#

Tags: c#

In my project I have to move the files in Main Folder Which locate in Sub-folders. the Below code move the First and second sub-folder files only. How can I move all the sub folders file to main folder.

**Calling function -**

```
MoveFilesToMain(@"F:\Test\New folder", @"F:\Test");
```

**Function -**

```
 public static void MoveFilesToMain(string sourceDirName, string destDirName)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {          
            File.Move(Path.Combine(sourceDirName, file.Name), Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name));
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            FileInfo[] files1 = subdir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files1)
            {                
                File.Move(Path.Combine(subdir.FullName, file.Name), Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Below marked folders files are not moved.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little bit of recursion should do the trick.

basically for a given source dir, we copy the files into the dest dir. then iterate through every sub dir in the source dir and repeat the process recursively.

```
public static void MoveFilesToMain(string sourceDirName, string destDirName)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

        if (files.Length == 0 && dirs.Length == 0)
        {
          Directory.Delete(sourceDirName, false);
          return;
        }

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {          
            File.Move(Path.Combine(sourceDirName, file.Name), Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name));
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
          MoveFilesToMain(subdir.FullName, destDirName)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks raja, but subdir.FullPath is not available in vs2010 So I have Changed as MoveFilesToMain(subdir.FullName, destDirName); .

Comment: Is possible to delete the empty folders only in C#

Comment: yes.. check if there are no files/sub directories in a directory and delete them..    if (Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirName).Length == 0 && 
            Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirName).Length == 0)
        {
            Directory.Delete(sourceDirName, false);
        }

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```